# WebStorm debug mode for Meteor npm script

Tags: node.js, debugging, meteor, webstorm

In WebStorm if I add run configuration as "Meteor" app then debugging works fine.

Recently we moved to use NPM script `npm start` to start our app. This helped us to reduce sending settings of WebStorm run config to other team members.

When I start NPM script in debug mode in WebStorm, then it doesn't hit the breakpoint. I want to know should I do some kind of change in 'run config' so that WebStorm knows that it should run Meteor debugger.

Here is my run script in package.json

```
{

  "scripts": {
    "start": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost/db meteor --settings private/settings.json",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meteor can only be debugged via [Meteor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/run-debug-configuration-meteor.html) run configuration; there is no way to debug it through NPM script.
You can specify environment variables and pass settings to Meteor right in your configuration

[image]